# apply rel attribute to <a> if child is img - jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes, css-selectors

I'm using jquery and am looking to dynamically add a rel attribute to  tag but only if it's child is an image to add rel="lightbox". Something like the following....

```
if('a').children(img){

            $(this).attr('rel', 'lightbox');
        }
```

Any help/ advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sub-selector using jQuery. Sub-selectors matches children of the parent match. Use either `space` or `>` to delimit sub-selector :

```
// find all "img" children of "a"
$('a > img').each(function(){ $(this).attr('rel', 'lightbox'); });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('a > img').parent().attr('rel', 'lightbox');
```

Comment: +1, but consider using `'a > img'` to only match direct children since you're using `parent()`.

Comment: Yeah that working, thanks Jacob! So much more efficent then how I was trying it too, I was over complicating it!

Answer (score 0):

$('img').parent('a').attr('rel', 'lightbox');

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this ? not sure !

```
$('a').find('img').each(function(i,v){
 $(v).parent().attr('rel','lightbox');
});
```

i like find() more than '>' because it much faster.